# XML error when clearing cache after composer update symfony 3.4.17

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I did a composer update to Symfony 3.4.17 and when it gets to the cache clear part, I get an error:

```
In XmlFileLoader.php line 370:

  Unable to parse file "/mnt/c/Development/tom/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/services.xml".

In XmlUtils.php line 101:
[ERROR 1840] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}argument', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'tagged' is not an element of the set {'collection', 'service', 'expression', 'string', 'constant', 'iterator'}.
```

In that file, I do see these lines:

```
    <service id="cache_warmer" class="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate" public="true">
        <argument type="tagged" tag="kernel.cache_warmer" />
    </service>
```

I'm using php 7.2 on WLS Ubuntu 16.04 with composer 1.7.2

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to manually delete cache files ?

Symfony uses some cached files that are no longer compatible with code updates. The cache:clear command no longer works.